# No device found on ttymxc3 (Arduino IDE, Udoo)

Tags: arduino

I want to use an Arduino to control an LED on UDOOBbuntu. I'm using Udoo Quad and I'm following [this example](http://www.udoo.org/tutorial/getting-started-with-arduino-ide-on-udoo/), but there is something wrong. [here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLc8m.jpg). I removed the original Arduino IDE and installed Arduino, but it didn't work. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to go tools > port and select one of the ports in that menu? It seems like your issue is that the Arduino is looking at the wrong serial port.